# Framework dependencies and linker flags

Tags: ios, frameworks, linker, dependencies

I have created my own framework for others to use, following Ray Wenderlich's framework tutorial.

All went well and I managed to build the framework and the bundle.

Thing is, when I copy them to a new project I need to link the project with MobileCoreServices and SystemConfigurations frameworks (even though they're already linked in my framework), and I need the user to add a `-ObjC`  `-all_loaded` linker flag because I'm using categories in my framework.

Are there any ways to get around it?
I want the user to be able to use it "straight out of the box". Just copy and run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.